# Efficient way to join a dataframe with an Oracle table without writing right

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas

In Python, using Pandas, I have a dataframe that I want to join with a table located in an Oracle database.
I do not have writing rights in the database. Therefore, I currently do:

```
#select the column you want to use to query
ID_list = data['ID']

#cut the list in chunks of 1000 to overcome Oracle limitation on SQL query
chunks = [ID_list[x:x+1000] for x in range(0, len(ID_list), 1000)]

#initiate connection to Oracle
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=XXX;UID=YYY;PWD=ZZZ')

#initiate an empty frame
df = pd.DataFrame()

#query each chunk of 1000 ID and append it to df
for chunk in chunks:
    sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE_X WHERE ID IN (' + ','.join(map(str, chunk)) + ')'
    df = df.append(pd.read_sql(sql_query, cnxn), ignore_index=True)
```

And then I would work on df and maybe merge it with data.
I'm sure it is far slower than an SQL join but I can't upload my dataframe.

Is that the most efficient solution ?

Comment: can't you just get all Oracle table to DataFrame and join both dataframes using pandas join operation?

Comment: @arturro Maybe not because of SQL query limitations

Comment: @arturro: in theory possible but the size of the table makes it impraticable and anyway more time consuming than the current code.